# Yii2. Can't store a url or "<script></script" in table field

Tags: php, yii2

In ActiveForm I have:

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'text')->textarea(['rows' => 10]) ?>
```

When I'm writing there any text, it works fine. But when I want to put there an url (like "https://instagram.com") or script tag, it throws 403 forbidden eror.

BTW, it works fine on my localhost, but on the server it throws such an error.

Comment: It looks more like problem with your server (too restrictive WAF), not application itself.

Comment: You need to provide more information: the content of the returned error message / your domain name / your target domain name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try escaping string before saving to the database.

Encode the data of the textarea before saving:

```
\yii\helpers\Html::encode($model->text)
```

and it's preferred to use prepared statements:

```
->where('status=:status', [':status' => $status])
```

follow:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-best-practices#avoiding-sql-injections

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-best-practices#avoiding-xss

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) to work with text with html tags.